# Google developers console, different consent screen settings for different users

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

We're developing one web application which has multiple user types access Google APIs via OAuth 2.0.

Is it possible to set up different consent screen settings for different user types. For example, user of accounting department will see product logo and product name of accounting.

Comment: No there is only one consent screen per project.  You cant change it programmatically either.   Your only option would be to create different project with different consent screens, but then you would have a problem with the fact you will have different Client_id's and they wont mix and match.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No there is only one consent screen per project. You can't change it programmatically either. Your only option would be to create different project with different consent screens, but then you would have a problem with the fact you will have different Client_id's and they wont mix and match.