# Configure multiple OAuth consent screens within one GCP project?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We have a GCP project which runs processes that are internal in nature. Some of these processed required us to configure OAuth clients and an OAuth consent screen which is restricted to internal users within the organisation. Some of these processes also require us to use restricted scopes. These restricted scopes are hence configured in the OAuth consent screen.

Now we have another application deployed in the same GCP project which uses OAuth for user authentication. This application needs to be external facing so that the users who do not belong to our organisation are able to login as well. This application does not have restricted scopes.

Is it possible to configure a different OAuth consent screen for this application within the same project ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google developers console, different consent screen settings for different users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482880/google-developers-console-different-consent-screen-settings-for-different-users)